# How to mix useCallback with useRef in functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I'm newish to React and am working on an infinite scroll component. Multiple components will use infinite scroll and need to be synchronized together (i.e., scrolling one element programmatically scrolls other components as well).

So I've created `ScrollProvider` which maintains scroll state among components (even if they're rerendered), and a lower level hook `useScrollSync.` useScrollState returns a ref and a handleScroll callback which modify the state in the scroll provider. That all works just fine. However, I separately want to measure a component's size. The example provided in by the React team shows a callback since that for sure will be executed once the component is mounted, and the element would not be null. The problem is that the div already has a ref from the useScrollSync hook.

**The core question**

*If I wanted to measure my div in addition to using scroll sync on it, how do I assign both a callback ref AND other ref to it? Is there a pattern around this, given that an element can only have one div?*

Some (simplified) code:

**ScrollProvider**

```
const ScrollContext = React.createCreateContext();

const ScrollProvider = ({initialScrollTop, initialScrollLeft}) => {
  const controlledElements = useRef(new Map());
  const scrollPositions = useRef({
    scrollTop: initialScrollTop, 
    scrollLeft: initialScrollLeft, 
    controllingElementKey: null
  });

  const register = (key, controlledElementRef) => {
    controlledElements.current.set(key, controlledElementRef);
  }

  const handleScrollHOF = (key) => { 
    return () => { 
      scrollPositions.controllingElementKey = key;
      //some scrolling logic
    }
  }

  return {register, scrollPositions, handleScrollHOF};

}
```

**useScrollSync**

```
const useScrollSync = () => { 
  const scrollContext = useContext(ScrollContext);

  const elementRef = useRef(null);
  const keyRef = useRef({key: Symbol()}); // this probably could also be useState

  useEffect(() => {
    scrollContext.register(keyRef, elementRef);
  }, []);

return {ref: elementRef, handleScroll: handleScrollHOF(keyRef.current)};
}
```

**SomeComponent (Round 1)**

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  // this would be within the provider tree
  const {ref, handleScroll} = useScrollSync();

  return (
    <div onScroll={handleScroll} ref={ref}>some stuff</div>
  )
}
```

Now the challenge is adding in a measurements hook...

**useMeasurements**

```
const useMeasurements = () => {
  // something like this, per the React team's Hooks FAQ
  const [measurements, setMeasurements] = useState(null);

  const measurementRef = useCallback((element) => {
    if(element !== null) {
      setMeasurements(element.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  });

  return {measurementRef, measurements};
}
```

In order to add this to SomeComponent...
**SomeComponent (Round 2)**

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  // this would be within the provider tree
  const {ref, handleScroll} = useScrollSync();
  const {measurementRef, measurements} = useMeasurements();
  // I cannot assign measurementRef to this same div, 
  // and changing useMeasurements to just measure an injected ref winds up
  // with that ref being null and it never being recalculated

  return (
    <div onScroll={handleScroll} ref={ref}>some stuff</div>
  )
}
```

I've sort of hit a wall here, or maybe I'm just overtired. Any thoughts on how to get beyond this?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see is that you aren't referencing a viable ref in useMeasurement. In addition, useCallback executes synchronously as part of rendering, before the DOM is created. You'll need to reference your element in another useEffect hook.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Michael. You can use a function as a reference as well. When the element changes, it will execute the fn and pass in the element itself. UseCallback simply memoizes it so the function reference is consistent between renders (and it, itself, doesn’t cause more renders). This pattern was found here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Comment: Ahhhhh! I forgot about that. I haven't had reason to use it and it got dumped into the heap behind my eyeballs.

Comment: It does seem to me, though, that if you passed the ref created by useScrollSync(), then used useEffect() when referencing it, you'd end up with your element available. Kinda cheezy having to pass refs through, but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It was coming in as null when I was trying, but maybe I was doing something small wrong. I’ll give it a shot I’m the morning. Many thanks

Comment: Would be more convenient (but maybe nonsensical) to be able to take two refs and assign them to the element. Probably too many possible race conditions that could happen though.

Comment: I'll check back in and see how it went. Good luck!

Comment: Anoher idea: create the ref in the main function, then pass it to each hook?

Comment: I ended up trying that this morning and it resolved the issue. Not sure what was happening last night. However, actual concern - I’m not sure of the downstream effect of  using a “useRef” ref rather than a “useCallback” ref.

Comment: It seems like they are different ways of managing. With useRef and useEffect, you end up with useEffect running after the component has been rendered. With ref={callback}, it looks like it is called in a similar space, but more specifically only when the referenced element changes. useEffect happens on every render.